# Updating and retrieving images (Asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
protected void upimg_about_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    con.Open();
    string sqlQuery = " UPDATE [dbo].[tbldetails] SET [image]=@image,[image2]=@image2 WHERE id=@id";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["email"].ToString());

    int img = Image1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    int img2 = Image2.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    byte[] msdata = new byte[img];
    byte[] msdata2 = new byte[img2];

    Image1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(msdata, 0, img);
    Image2.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(msdata2, 0, img2);

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", msdata);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image2", msdata2);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    data1.Text="Image Updated Successfully";    
}
```

This is the code I am using to update the images in the database.

The user when required can update the images (eg: in the firstpage.aspx) and can retrieve it in the next page (nextpage.aspx).

But the problem is: suppose a user wants to update just a single image and he/she upload's the image and clicks the update button and when retrieving images in the next page the image that was updated is visible but the one which is already present in the database is not. I am not sure but during the updation the other fileupload is empty is this why this is happening? Is there other way to do it?

PS: I have textboxes in the firstpage.aspx in which i am retrieving the text he/she has already put in the database and hence when the user wants to make changes it can be done easily.

```
TextBox1.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
TextBox2.Text = dr["address"].ToString();
```

So, is it possible to retrieve the image path which the user has previously submitted? Or any way in which the user can update a single image and during retrieval both the images can be retrieved?

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your code up so that you can send 1 image at a time to the DB.  Then pass the corresponding `FileUpload` and SQL Column name to your function.  Conditionally send the new file to the database depending on whether the `FileUpload` contains a file.  You can check this by looking at the `HasFile` property.

```
protected void upimg_about_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    // make sure at least 1 file
    if (!Image1.HasFile && !Image2.HasFile)
    {
        data1.Text="No Images Uploaded";
        return;
    }

    con.Open();
    UploadImage(Image1, "[image]");
    UploadImage(Image2, "[image2]");
    con.Close();

    data1.Text = "Image Updated Successfully";    
}

void UploadImage(FileUpload fileUpload, string columnName)
{
    if (!fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        return;
    }

    string sqlQuery = "UPDATE [dbo].[tbldetails] SET " + columnName + "=@image WHERE id=@id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["email"].ToString());

    int img = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] msdata = new byte[img];
    fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(msdata, 0, img);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", msdata);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Its showing Image Updated successfully even when there is no image uploaded

Comment: Are the images getting saved to the database?  Unless I have a logical error here (`!Image1.HasFile && !Image2.HasFile`) the function should exit when there are no images uploaded.